# (igraph Python) g.neighbors(vertex, mode="out") returns unexplainable list

Tags: python, igraph

I have a graph 'g' and I'm working with igraph. When I run 
`g.neighbors(vertex, mode="out")` it returns me this list, where the numbers are the nodes ids:

```
[16, 78, 110, 114, 179, 227, 350, 366, 426]
[78]
[213]
[300]
[163, 371]
[]
```

The problem is it should give me :

```
[17, 79, 112, 116, 181, 229, 352, 368, 428]
[79]
[215]
[302]
[165, 373]
[]
```

I checked the real ids of the neighbors with "`g.shortest_paths_dijkstra()`" and I looked inside the original `.gml` file.

I really don't understand why "`neighbors(vertex, mode="out")`" is adding +1 or +2 to the neighbors ids...

Comment: is your graph directed or undirected and did you call it with `mode='all'` (like you say in the title) or `mode='out'` (like you say in the description)

Comment: Hi @bunji thanks for your answer! I run it with mode="out" (sorry) and it is a directed graph

Comment: igraph doesn't use the node IDs from the file directly... it renumbers them as an array. so if e.g. you have a file with a couple of missing IDs, this can happen (i've used graphml, where the nodes had named IDs which were changed in igraph). lt looks like you have a noncontiguous ID before 16 (since 16 and 78 are one off) and another one between 78 and 110 (since 110 is two off). can you verify one of the target nodes using g.vs[id] and checking against expected attributes?

Comment: Hi Corley, sorry for the delay. Thanks a lot this is exactly the problem! In fact, I have a initial graph and before doing g.neighbors(vertex, mode="out"), I delete some nodes with g.delete_vertices(). I assumed the graph was then updated and that g.neighbors(vertex, mode="out") was dealing with this new graph but it seems to take into account the "old" graph (crazy, because it is still g). Do you have any idea to make this new graph the reference? Or should I adapt the nodes "ids"?